# How can I find a forum by JWT Token?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find forum by JWT Token .. so if a user made 3 forum I want to list them.

My Request shows this way :

```
###
http://localhost:8080/forum/getByOwnerID
Authorization: Bearer {{adminToken}}
```

Or this way :

```
###
http://localhost:8080/forum/getByOwnerID
Authorization: Bearer {{userToken}}
```

On both I want to find the forum which they have made..

I create a function like that :

```
exports.getByToken = async (req, res, next) => {
  const forum = await Forum.findById(req.token._id);

  if (forum) {
    res.json(forum);
  } else {
    res.status(404).json({ message: "Forum not found" });
  }

  res.json(forum);
}
```

But the result is Forum not found :/

My ForumModel.js :

```
const forumSchema = ({
    forumName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    forumDescription: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    user: { 
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        
        ref: "User"
    },
    published_on: {
        type: String,
        default: moment().format("LLL")
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you passed those things in the token, Here is how you should do it.

```
const { forum:{ _id }} = req.user
```

All in to find the current user you should do something like this

```
const currentUser = req.user;
```

Am assuming the endpoint your working on is protected with jwt authentication.

Comment: I did not understand the first answer how should this work ??

Comment: That is destructuring! how ever it is nested.